# Can i get attribute value as a result soapCall?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I call soap as follows:

```
 $context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
    'verify_peer'       => false,
    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
 ]);
 $soapClient = new SoapClient('my_url', [
     'connection_timeout' => '60',
     'stream_context'     => $context,
     'trace'              => 1,
     'cache_wsdl'         => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
 ]);
 $response = $soapClient->__soapCall('create', array($soapParameters));
```

Result should be something like this:

```
<SOAP>
  <BEGIN>
    <STATUS Value="OK">
    <CATEGORY Value="12">
  </BEGIN>
</SOAP>
```

But here is result:
{
 "BEGIN":{
   "STATUS":"",
   "CATEGORY":""
  }
}

Comment: How did you print that result? can you print it using `var_dump()` or `print_r()` ? if you needed to be manual there is http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

Comment: $response = $soapClient->__soapCall('create', array($soapParameters)); var_dump($response);

Comment: object(stdClass)#522 (1) {
    ["BEGIN"]=>
    object(stdClass)#523 (4) {
      ["STATUS "]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["CATEGORY "]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }

Comment: Hrm, so there data simply isn't there, I have a feeling you're going to need to parse the XML manually with SimpleXML or the DOM library in PHP.

Comment: Possible Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959839/php-soapclient-returning-attribute-values-in-a-response/8078127#8078127

Comment: Can I get xml from __soapCall?

Comment: Sorry, replacement link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php